# Values received via http post are null with AngularJS and Web api 2

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, http-post

I followed a tutorial and wanted to expand the functionality of already existing code. Code: https://send.firefox.com/download/27d75a7398f351c9/#wKkjkAuvlpBVOMKx9szFHA

It's using angularJS as the frontend and webapi 2 aspnet with entitiyframework. The problem is that my http posts are sending null values. I am guessing I have to post it in the right format, but im not sure how exactly to do it.

I tried transforming it into an object but it still received as null.

controller.js

```
function save(contact) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/api/Contact/' + contact).success(function (results) {
            $scope.contact = results;
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject('Failed saving contact');
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

fails at db.Contacts.Add(Contact); (null error)

```
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Contact Contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Console.Write("post contact");
                Console.Write(Contact);
                db.Contacts.Add(Contact);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Contact);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = Contact.Id }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
```

Tried sending this:

```
{Name: "test", Address: "test", City: "teee", Country: "tesd"}
```

Edit:

After trying to save the contact with the `save` function:

[output of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/merqE.png)
Request URL: http://localhost:64158/api/Contact/[object%20Object]

If i open the [object%20Object] in a new tab from the network view i get this:

```
<Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
<MessageDetail>
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'SampleEF6.Models.Contact Get(Int32)' in 'SampleEF6.Controllers.ContactController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please use Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools. Please share with us the **exact** url being posted to. And the **exact** payload being posted.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `contact` when that code runs in JS? *`console.log` it to be sure.*

Comment: I have added more information. I am guessing what's in the url is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending the data wrong. You're supposed to send the data (contact in this example) in the body of the request, instead of the url.

Try `$http.post('/api/Contact/', contact)`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post